# CMake: it doesn't curl the right way

Tags: linux, macos, curl, linker, cmake

Together with a friend, I am trying to fix us a working CMake file that we can use on a scripting language's build.

It works, for the most part. The problem is with CURL.

In a nutshell: it works for me, but not for him.

Differences:
- I have OS X 10.11.1 with default libcurl
- He has ubuntu 13.x with default libcurl

For me it is: `/usr/lib/libcurl.dylib`
For him it is: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so`

It works on my end, but on his, the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder doesnt seem to get noticed.

Basically, we see a lot of linkage errors; descripting undefined symbols. The ones that seem to be un-linkable:

- `curl_easy_getinfo`
- `curl_version_info`
- `curl_slist_free_all`
- `curl_easy_duphandle`
- `curl_easy_setopt`
- `curl_easy_reset`
- `curl_easy_perform`
- `curl_easy_cleanup``
- `curl_formfree`
- `curl_slist_append`
- `curl_easy_init`

The build command that fails:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/os.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/os.dir/os.cpp.o  -o os -rdynamic -lcurl -lmysqlclient -ldl libmpfd.a libobjectscript.a lib/libsoci_core.so.3.2.2 lib/libsoci_mysql.so.3.2.2 -lmysqlclient lib/libsoci_core.so.3.2.2 -lpthread -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/craft/Downloads/objectscript/build/lib:
```

Output alltogether: http://pastebin.com/7dHCvDTe

The CMakeLists file we use: http://pastebin.com/0sbzdWr4

I am so totally lost... I have tried:

- ...to add the directory of the library using `link_directories`
- ...to use a different find_package
- ...to utilize `curl-config --libs` and pasting that output at the end of the link flags

But none of them worked. So, it would be really awesome if someone could lend a hand here.

What i would like to know is:

- Why is CURL not picking up the library? I only see `-lcurl` in his command - but on my Mac, it actually puts the full path to the dylib.
- What have I done wrong in my CMakeLists file that prevents CURL to work?
- Is there a general advice for trying to debug such issues?

Comment: Please, create [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), code of 380 lines is too long.

Comment: Are you sure you added the libraries in the right way? Place curl a second time to be the very right target. Tsyvarev is right: Your example is way to too long. Additionally, you use CMake as it would be Make. You have code that is not necessary like handling libcurl not found. Everything is done by CMake but in a better way.s